# wordpress database import download empty files

Tags: mysql, wordpress, import

I come here because no one can help me in Wordpress forum.
I change server for a Wordpress, install clean, upload the files, themes and plugin :

everything is perfect.

Then i import the database
I cant login anymore. Every time i click on a link or try to login to the admin section, the browser download the pages i am calling or a empty download.php file.

the site is at http://stardust4d.com/Stardust4D/

I search the question here and didn't see something similar. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links are pointing to startdust-group.com, not stardust4d.com.

Export the original database, open up notepad++, geany, or similar, open the .sql export file, and do a search and replace over the entire document.

You will want to replace all stardust-group.com strings with stardust4d.com

Comment: Tanxs so much, this was killing me, first real answers in a month!